# for beginners | luhn algorithm for list of integers

Tags: haskell, luhn

I have already seen this solution:

```
doubleAndSum :: [Int] -> Int
doubleAndSum = fst . foldr (\i (acc, even) -> (acc + nextStep even i, not even)) (0,False)
  where 
    nextStep even i
        | even      = (uncurry (+) . (`divMod` 10) . (*2)) i
        | otherwise = i 

myLuhn :: Int -> Bool
myLuhn = (0 ==) . (`mod` 10) . doubleAndSum . (map (read . (: ""))) . show

testCC :: [Bool]
testCC = map myLuhn [49927398716, 49927398717, 1234567812345678, 1234567812345670]
-- => [True,False,False,True]
```

However, I don't understand it because I am new to Haskell.

```
luhn :: [Int] -> Bool
luhn w x y z = (luhnDouble w + x + luhnDouble y + z) `mod` 10 == 0

luhnDouble :: Int -> Int
luhnDouble x | 2* x <= 9 = 2*x
             | otherwise = (2*x)-9
```

I understand this simplified version of the algorithm for only four digits.

However, I don't know how to write a version of the algorithm for a list of digits of any length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, the example is pretty arcane. It makes excessive use of *point-free style*, i.e. omitting explicit function arguments. That can *sometimes* make code nice and concise, but it can also make code rather cryptic.

Let's start with this here:

```
     (uncurry (+) . (`divMod` 10) . (*2)) i
```

First, since you're just applying everything to the argument `i`, there's no real need for having a *composition pipeline* – you might as well write it

```
     uncurry (+) $ (`divMod` 10) $ (*2) i
   ≡ uncurry (+) $ (`divMod` 10) $ i*2
   ≡ uncurry (+) $ (i*2)`divMod`10
   ≡ let (d,r) = (i*2)`divMod`10
     in d+r
```

So, `nextStep` could be written

```
    nextStep isEven i
        | isEven     = d+r
        | otherwise  = i
     where (d,r) = (i*2)`divMod`10
```

(I avoid the variable name `even`, which is also the name of the standard function that checks whether a number is even!)

Alternatively, you could just invoke your `luhnDouble` function here, which actually computes the same thing, just in a more verbose way:

```
    nextStep isEven i
        | isEven     = luhnDouble i
        | otherwise  = i
```

Then you have this fold. It basically does three things interlocked: **1.** toggle between even and odd **2.** apply `nextStep` to each list element, together with the even-ness **3.** sum up the results.

I don't agree that it's a good idea to do all of that with a single fold<sup>†</sup>; much clearer to write it out:

```
doubleAndSum = sum
              . map (\(isEven, i) -> nextStep isEven i)  -- or `map (uncurry nextStep)`
              . zip (cycle [False, True])   -- or `iterate not False`
              . reverse
```

The `reverse` is needed just to align the `False` with the *last* element of the input list, instead of its head; this is a bit ugly but uncritical.

The combination of `map` and `zip` has a standard shortcut that does both in one step:

```
doubleAndSum = sum
              . zipWith nextStep (cycle [False, True])
              . reverse
```

As for `myLuhn`: this is IMO actually ok to write in the point-free style, but I'd break it out a bit. Specifically,

```
decimalDigits :: Int -> [Int]
decimalDigits = map (read . (: "")) . show
```

What `(:"")` does is, it puts single characters into singleton-strings. Could also be written `read . pure`.

Then,

```
myLuhn = (0 ==) . (`mod` 10) . doubleAndSum . decimalDigits
```

or

```
myLuhn x = doubleAndSum (decimalDigits x)`mod`10 == 0
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>There could be a case made that a single traversal is good for performance, however if you think on that level then it should almost certainly not be a *lazy right fold over a list*, but rather a strict left fold over an unboxed vector. Anyway, GHC can often fuse separate fold-y operations into a single traversal.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for decoding this pretentious code. :-)   Also, [`Data.Char.digitToInt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:digitToInt) is probably better than `read . (: "")` in at least two ways.

Comment: Sure, how could I miss that!